# Need help in determining equivalent method for creating Labels in Apache POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi

We have been using jExcel API for reading and writing of Excel 2003 files. Now we have to switch to Apache POI to provide support for XLS and XSLX file formats.

Could anyone help me in determining the equivalent for the below code snippet:

```
jxl.write.Label userLabel = 
        new jxl.write.Label(int column, int row, String, CellFormat);
sheet.addCell(userLabel);
```

I am a bit confused in rewriting the above code using the Apache POI SS UserModel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a JXL Label is just a cell that contains text. If so, your code would then be something like:

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(row);
Cell c = r.getCell(column);
if(c == null) {
   c = r.createCell(column);
}
c.setCellValue(text);
c.setCellStyle(cellFormat);
```